# how to remove everything before second occurance of underscore

Tags: php

I couldn't find the solution using search.

I am looking for a php solution to remove all character BEFORE the second occurance of and underscore (including the underscore)

For example:

**this_is_a_test**

Should output as:

**a_test**

I currently have this code but it will remove everything after the first occurance:

```
preg_replace('/^[^_]*.s*/', '$1', 'this_is_a_test');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a slightly different approach,

```
$s='this_is_a_test';
echo implode('_', array_slice( explode( '_', $s ),2 ) );

/* outputs */
a_test
```

Comment: this looks most elegant of all the solutions. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
preg_replace('/^.*_.*_(.*)$/U', '$1', 'this_is_a_test');
```

Note the `U` modifier which tells regex to take as less characters for `.*` as possible.

Comment: this works and you were the first to respond. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `explode`, `implode` along with `array_splice` like as

```
$str = "this_is_a_test";
echo implode('_',array_splice(explode('_',$str),2));//a_test
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/432091)

Comment: thank you, this seems to be the easiest to understand

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
<?php
    $string = 'this_is_a_test';
    $explode = explode('_', $string, 3);
    echo $explode[2];
?>
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/432092)

Answer (score 0):

Why go the complicated way? This is a suggestion though using `strrpos` and `substr`:

```
<?php
$str = "this_is_a_test";

$str_pos = strrpos($str, "_");

echo substr($str, $str_pos-1);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still in favor of a regular expression in this case:

```
preg_replace('/^.*?_.*?_/', '', 'this_is_a_test');
```

Or (which looks more complex here but is easily adjustable to N..M underscores):

```
preg_replace('/^(?:.*?_){2}/', '', 'this_is_a_test');
```

The use of the question mark in `.*?` makes the match non-greedy; and *the pattern has been expanded from the original post to "match up through" the second underscore*.

Since the goal is to *remove* text the matched portion is simply replaced with an empty string - there is no need for a capture group or to use such as the replacement value.

If the input doesn't include two underscores then nothing is removed; such can be adjusted, very easily with the second regular expression, if the rules are further clarified.